# Sphinx wordforms Street/Saint?

Tags: sphinx

I tried to wordform

```
St > Street
St. > Saint
```

Yet when I tried to rotate it it thinks I am duplicating "St". How can I tell it in this one case I mean the period to be in the wordform since I' gathering it is one of the non-indexing chars so sees "St" as equal to "St."?

Answer (score 0):

You would need . in your `charset_table`, to be able to use it in wordforms.

Comment: Do you mean I need to add "St." in my char_set or "."?

Comment: charset_table is for single charactors.